# Unrecognized references across different Windows & Office versions

Tags: vba, excel

I need the ListView control for a VBA project. To use it, I referenced Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6) and drew a GUI in Office 2010 on Windows 7 (64-bit) containing the ListView object. When I opened the VBA project at work (Office 2007 on Windows XP), an error message said "Can't load the object because it's not available on this machine". When I opened the References dialog, I saw this:
[image: References dialog]

There are two "Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6)" items: one "MISSING" and one available (but unchecked). The file paths are different: the missing one is supposed to be located in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOMCTL.OCX, while the available one is located in C:\Windows\system32\MSCOMCTL.OCX.

Why isn't Excel/VBA able to use the available reference? Are these libraries different, despite having the same name? Is one a 64-bit version and the other one a 32-bit one (both Office versions are 32-bit if I recall correctly). How to make my VBA project inter-operable across different Windows or Office versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both versions of Office are 32-bit, I would hazard a guess that the CPU/OS on your home machine is 64-bit, but your work machine is 32-bit.  When you have a 32-bit CPU and OS, the drivers are all 32-bit and located in the System32 folder.  On a 64-bit CPU/OS, the 64-bit drivers are located in the System32 folder (confusing I know) and the 32-bit ones are located in the SysWOW64 folder.

If you set the path to "C:\Windows\system32\MSCOMCTL.OCX", it should work on both machines because windows will automatically [redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) your app to use the SysWOW64 path if necessary, with a few caveats listed on the linked page.

Comment: I see you deleted the comment, let me know what you find!

Comment: You're right, using the reference located in system32 works on both machines, thanks!